# Minimal Model, from formula

Tags: logic

{p2 ^ p3 -> p1, p3 ^ p4 -> p2, .... p9 ^ p10 -> p8}

Find the minimal model.

My professor told me the answer is the empty set,
but aren't these minimal models too?:
{p1}, {p2}, {p3}, {p4}, {p5}, {p6}, {p7}, {p8}, {p9}, {p10}

Answer (score 2):

If you agree that the empty set is a model, then certainly it is the minimal model.  It is definitely a "smaller" model than any you propose.  More directly, you have no basis for asserting any of the propositions.  For any set of [Horn clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause), if you don't have any facts then the minimal model is the empty set.